# Check if Two Ids exist in a MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, database

My table has these two ids: IDUser | followingID.

IDUser is the logged in users ID. FollowingID is the ID of the user they want to follow.

I now want to check if their relationship already exists in the following database:

I've tried:

```
SELECT EXISTS IdUser, followingID FROM following WHERE $id, $followingId"
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

What would the query be to check if two IDs already exist in a database. Both must exist and must be together in a relationship, not separately. IdUser and followingID are two separate columns showing side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IdUser, followingID FROM following WHERE IdUser = $id AND $followingId = followingID
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to check if the relationship already exists, you need to check the ID on both columns.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    following
WHERE   (IDUser = $id AND followingID = $followingID) OR
        (followingID = $id AND IDUser = $followingID)
```

if you want to manipulate the result by only showing `YES/NO` for the existing of the relationship,

```
SELECT  IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'YES', 'NO') Result
FROM    following
WHERE   (IDUser = $id AND followingID = $followingID) OR
        (followingID = $id AND IDUser = $followingID)
```

Comment: + First thorough answer.

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily need to check both relationships. Just because one user is following another, doesn't mean that same user is following the user that is following them.

Comment: when you say relationship, does it means both id are following with each other?

Answer (score 1):

You can count the rows where you have such entries.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM following 
WHERE IdUser = $id 
AND followingID =  $followingId
```